# "Trap the mouse" game, ai to avoid getting trapped

Tags: algorithm

I have a school assignment which is to build a simple game like this one: https://www.mathplayground.com/logic_trap_the_mouse.html

I have the base game done; The objective of the game is to trap the rat by making walls around it, the objective of the rat is to avoid these walls and reach the borders of the board, escaping the player. My problem is about the algorithm used to make the mouse move while at the same time avoiding walls until reaching the a border hexagon. How can I do this?

My idea: Using a pathfinder algorithm that tries to go to the nearest border cell. But this way the rat isn't really avoiding getting trapped. Or is it sufficient?

P.S.: I might be overthinking this

Comment: It might not always be optimal, but it's a good start. Try A* or Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: @masonk going to give it a shot but not sure if the ai is going to perform as expected (avoid getting trapped)

Comment: The next level up from this is to treat it as a 2-player game and try variations of a minmax decision rule

Comment: So like I could add a "distanceToNearestWall" factor?

Comment: First implement A* search. After you do that I expect you'd be able to use it as part of a minmax search.